# VB.Net program minimized not working

Tags: vb.net, system-tray

I have a code like below

```
 Private Sub InterfaceProg_Resize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
    'program minimized
    Try
        If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
            Me.Visible = True
            NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
            NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1, "Browser Bandwidth Optimizer", "Program Minimized", ToolTipIcon.Info)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The code is working fine but there is one problem. 
When i press the minimize button on top right, the program go to system tray
When i press close button, the program also go to system also go to system tray.

i want to make the program go to system tray if user press close button only and minimized the program to taskbar if user press minimized. how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the FormClosing event instead of the Resize event:

```
Private CloseAllowed As Boolean

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    If Not CloseAllowed And e.CloseReason <> CloseReason.WindowsShutDown Then
        Me.Hide()
        e.Cancel = True
        NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
        '' etc..
    End If
End Sub
```

You still need to give the user a way to exit the program.  The context menu for the NotifyIcon is the usual approach.  Add an Exit item:

```
Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    CloseAllowed = True
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to call your Code of "InterfaceProg_Resize" in the form closing even.
So make a new sub "Private Sub ProgToTray()"

Also you don't need a try catch for it.
You also need to hide the Taskbar Icon "Me.ShowInTaskbar = False"
And minimize the form"Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized"

```
Private Sub ProgToTray()

    Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
    NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1, "Browser Bandwidth Optimizer", "Program Minimized", ToolTipIcon.Info)

End Sub
```

If the user clicks x on your form ,Then you need to Cancel the closing of the form in the FormClosing event."e.Cancel = True"
Then you call "ProgToTray()"

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing

    e.Cancel = True
    ProgToTray()

End Sub
```

Then if you close the form with x it will go to the notify area.

Don't forget to make a click event to open the form again from the notify icon and an option so the user can exit the form.

To make an exit button you need to add a ContextMenuStrip1 to your form .
[image]

To open the ContextMenuStrip1 when you right click the NotifyIcon1 you need add the code "ContextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position)" to you NotifyIcon1 click event

You also need to check which button is clicked.
"If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then"  for the right button.
and
 
"e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then" for the left button.

So if the user clicks left the form will open again and when he clicks right the ContextMenuStrip1 will show.

If the user clicks left mouse button you set the formwindowstate back to normal.
Also show the taskbar icon again and hide the tray icon.

```
    Private Sub NotifyIcon1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles NotifyIcon1.MouseClick

    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        ContextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position)
    ElseIf e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        Me.ShowInTaskbar = True
        NotifyIcon1.Visible = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Then you make an click event for the exit button and remove the handler for the form closing event "RemoveHandler MyBase.FormClosing, AddressOf Form1_FormClosing".
The canceling of closing the form will not take place.
Then call me.close()

```
Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    RemoveHandler MyBase.FormClosing, AddressOf Form1_FormClosing
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: How is he going to close his form then?

Comment: forgot to post that part. i put it in my answer now.

Comment: thx.. it work perfectly. just one thing more but i already solve it. when i use me.close() the program still run in the taskbar eventhough the program appear to be close. currently i use "end" at the toolstripmenu

Comment: @user2364790 on my computer it work perfectly. i even installed it to test it.no problem. So i don't know why it happens. but you already fixed it :). good.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you press the `minimize` or `close` buttons a *WM_SYSCOMMAND* message is sent. The *WPARAM* specifies which button is pressed:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If m.Msg = &H112 Then 'WM_SYSCOMMAND 
        If CInt(m.WParam) = &HF060 Then 'SC_CLOSE, the close button is pressed
            Me.Visible = False
            Me.ShowInTaskbar = False

            Return 'cancel the message
        End If

        If CInt(m.WParam) = &HF020 Then 'SC_MINIMIZE, the minimize button is pressed
            'do your staff

        End If
    End If

    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

[WM_SYSCOMMAND message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360(v=vs.85).aspx)